# getting angular material table to work properly with api call

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to get Angular material table to work with an api call to my database I get the right data I just want to display with the new material table and for some reason this is not working as expected.

this is my main component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AosService} from './app.aos.service.component'
import {QuoteModel} from './QuoteModel'
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-aos',
  providers: [AosService],
  templateUrl: './app.aos.quoteQuery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.aos.quoteQuery.component.scss']
})
export class AOSAppComponent {
    displayedColumns = ['OrdNbr', 'sotypeid', 'user6', 'LUpd_DateTime', 'User3', 'crtd_user', 'S4Future01', 'SlsperID', 'TotMerch', 'CustOrdNbr'];
    DataSource;
    public datas;
    public hidData = true;

    constructor(private _aosService: AosService) {

    }

    getAosQuote(quote: string) {
      this._aosService.getQuoteQueryData(quote.toUpperCase()).subscribe(res => {
        this.hidData = false;
       this.DataSource = res.recordset;
        console.log(this.DataSource);
      })  
    }
}
```

this is my service module making the call

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {QuoteModel} from './QuoteModel'

@Injectable()
export class AosService {
    private headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    private aosUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/api/query/'

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getQuoteQueryData(quote: string) {
        return this.http.get(this.aosUrl + quote, this.options)
            .map((res: any) => res.json())
            .catch((error: Response) => [{ status: error }]);
    }
}
```

I am getting data back in my console.log statement

[image]

this is my html

```
<app-aos-header></app-aos-header>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <md-input-container class="aos-full-width">
            <input type="search" (keyup.enter)="getAosQuote(quote.value)" #quote mdInput placeholder="Quote Number" required>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="getAosQuote(quote.value)" type="button">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div [hidden]="hidData" class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="CustOrdNbr">
            <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Customer Order Number </md-header-cell>
            <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.CustOrdNbr}} </md-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="LUpd_DateTime">
            <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Last Update </md-header-cell>
            <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.LUpd_DateTime}}% </md-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="OrdNbr">
            <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Order Number </md-header-cell>
            <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.OrdNbr}} </md-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="S4Future01">
            <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Future</md-header-cell>
            <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.S4Future01}} </md-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="SlsperID">
            <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Sales person</md-header-cell>
            <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.SlsperID}} </md-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="TotMerch">
            <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Total Merchandise</md-header-cell>
            <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.TotMerch}} </md-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="User3">
            <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>User 3</md-header-cell>
            <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.User3}} </md-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="crtd_user">
            <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>crtd_user</md-header-cell>
            <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.crtd_user}} </md-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="sotypeid">
            <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>SO Type</md-header-cell>
            <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.sotypeid}} </md-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="user6">
            <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>user 6</md-header-cell>
            <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.user6}} </md-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
        <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
    </md-table>
</div>
```

I am getting my table headers but no data in the cdkCellDef
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right track with the code you provided in the comments. To pass the `quote` to service, you need add an addition parameter to the `constructor` of  `AOSDataSource` class. Then you can pass the `quote` value from your component when created the instance of `AOSDataSource` from `getAosQuote` function.

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mkQ2Qx8qLVO2uHJdmulb?p=preview)

ts:

```
export class AOSAppComponent {

  displayedColumns = ['OrdNbr', 'sotypeid', 'user6', 'LUpd_DateTime', 'User3', 'crtd_user', 'S4Future01', 'SlsperID', 'TotMerch', 'CustOrdNbr'];
  dataSource: AOSDataSource | null;

  tableVisible = false;

  constructor(private appState: AppState){ }

  getAosQuote(quote: string, keepFocus: boolean) {

    if(!this.tableVisible){
     setTimeout(() => { 
        document.getElementById('quote').blur();
        if(keepFocus){
          document.getElementById('quote').focus();
        }
        this.tableVisible = true}, 
      2000) 
    }
    this.dataSource = new AOSDataSource(this.appState, quote);
  }  
}

export class AOSDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private appState: AppState, private quote: String) {
    super();
  }

  subject: BehaviorSubject<[]> = new BehaviorSubject<[]>([]);

  connect(): Observable<[]> {
      console.log('connect');
      if (!this.subject.isStopped)
          this.appState.getQuoteQueryData(this.quote.toUpperCase())
              .subscribe({
                next: (value) => {
                  console.log(value);
                  this.subject.next(value);
                }
              });
      return Observable.merge(this.subject);
  }

  disconnect() {
      this.subject.complete();
      this.subject.observers = [];
  }
}
```

Note: I added an extra `boolean` flag and `setTimeout` in the `getAosQuote` function because I was running into problem where, right after initialization, the table requires couple seconds and an event to trigger `connect()` and render the data. So, I added that as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

your variable datasource in the your component has name Datasource and in your html is datasource

```
 this.DataSource = res.recordset;   


<md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

you need change to:

```
<md-table #table [dataSource]="DataSource">
```

or change the Datasource to datasource.

Comment: I changed DataSource to dataSource now I am getting an error dataSource.connect is not a function; I did do changedection like this private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) in my constructor then did this after my call this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

Comment: ah I see, can you do this dataSource:DataSource cause missing type of variable and you need a type DataSource variable.  I saw the examples here https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview and they use a class called ExampleDataSource that exends DataSource, i don't know if you need to do an extra class.

Comment: so I gave it this public dataSource: DataSource<any>; because it required a type argument and still get the same error

Comment: for some reason I think it has to do with this export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<MyGithubIssue> {
  constructor(private _exampleDatabase: ExampleHttpDatabase) {
    super();
  }

  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<UserData[]> {
    return this._exampleDatabase.getRepoIssues();
  }

  disconnect() {}
}
but this is not what I want to do I want to pass it to my service pass in my input then get my result back idk really want to use this but frustrating

Comment: I did figure out that there is now a this.dataSource.connect and a this.dataSource.disconnect; however setting this.dataSource.connect = res.recordset throws an error of cannot set propert of connect of undefined

Comment: check this example, you need to do something like that  https://plnkr.co/edit/ivvQqO5dXB92IXN8zOFv?p=preview

Comment: so that is all good and fine but not totally sure how I would pass my parameter around and where the hell is ExampleDataSource so to do this like me instead of ngOninit I would do this  getAosQuote(quote: string) {
      this.dataSource = new AOSDataSource(this._aosService);
      
    }  then

Comment: export class AOSDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
       constructor(private _aosService: AosService) {
           super();
       }
       subject: BehaviorSubject<QuoteModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<QuoteModel[]>([]);
       connect(): Observable<QuoteModel[]> {
           this._aosService.getQuoteQueryData(quote.toUpperCase()).subscribe(res => {
            this.subject = res;
           });
           return Observable.merge(this.subject);
       }
       disconnect() {
           this.subject.complete();
           this.subject.observers = [];
       }
   }

Comment: but I still need to pass around that quote variable and not sure how

Comment: so just to get my stuff working I switch to bootstrap and used bootstrap table the normal way and implemented pageiniation. I want to use material but for now I am not sure how to fix this issue. I did read on their page that they are going to be simplifying this soon